# MS SQL Server, Bulk Insert failing insert file in UTF-16 BE

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, bulkinsert, utf-16, bcp

I have a problem with Bulk Insert on MS SQL Server 2012. Input file is saved in UTF-16 BE.

```
BULK INSERT Positions
FROM 'C:\DEV\Test\seq.filename.csv'
WITH
  (
    DATAFILETYPE = 'widechar',
    FORMATFILE = 'C:\DEV\Test\Format.xml'
  );
```

Fortmat file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<BCPFORMAT xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sqlserver/2004/bulkload/format" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
  <RECORD>
    <FIELD ID="ActionCode" xsi:type="NCharFixed" LENGTH="4" />
    <FIELD ID="T1" xsi:type="NCharFixed" LENGTH="2" /> 
    <FIELD ID="ReofferCounter" xsi:type="NCharFixed" LENGTH="6" />
    <FIELD ID="T1" xsi:type="NCharFixed" LENGTH="2" /> 
    ... other fields....

  </RECORD>
  <ROW>
    <COLUMN SOURCE="ActionCode" NAME="DT" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" LENGTH="255" />
    <COLUMN SOURCE="ReofferCounter" NAME="NO" xsi:type="SQLNCHAR" LENGTH="255" />
  </ROW>
</BCPFORMAT>
```

Input file sample:

```
02|+00|... other cols.... 
02|+00|... other cols....
```

[image]

I have two problems:

1) If the input file has encoding UTF-16 BE, I get only chinesee characters instead of numbers.

2) If I convert the input file to the UTF-16 LE, I see correct characters, but the character data are shifted one character to the left - as if BOM was parsed (and counted as 1 character), but not transformed to the output (which I do not desire).

[image: first column strange data]

Questions:

1) I there a way, how to import a file in UTF-16 BE withou conversion to LE?

2) What causes the shift and how to avoid it?